# Using closure properties to show that $a^n b^m a^{n+m}$ is not regular

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I want to show that $L = \{a^n b^m a^{n+m} \mid n, m \geq 0\}$ is not regular.

Can I say that the complement of $L$ intersected with $a^*b^*$ equals $\{a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ and since I know that $\{a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ is not regular, then $L$ is not regular?

Or would I have to use the pumping lemma?

Comment: You can do whatever you want as long as it's logically valid.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Does that make sense tho? Like I guess is that true?

Comment: That's for you to answer. Try to be more confident in your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of reasoning can work in principle; you are trying to use closure properties of REG for a proof of contradiction. Make sure you understand that that's what you're doing.

Unfortunately, you do not get $\{a^nb^n\}$. For instance, $a^3 b^4 \in \overline{L} \cap a^*b^*$. Check out our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) for more techniques you can try.

Comment: Actually can I just use the pumping lemma and state $a^0b^pa^p$ is in the language, then y = $a^k$ with 0 < k <= p, choose i = 0 so I get $a^{−k}b^pa^p$ which is not in the language?

Comment: @user270494 No, it wouldn't work like that. I recommend you visit [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/843/98).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What do you get when you intersect $L$ with the language denoted by $b^*a^*$? It won't be quite what you need, but it's close. You can then get the $b^ma^m$ language by subtracting (i.e., set difference) some regular language from that.